# How to pass two models in a single a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC, I created two model classes, `User` and `Address`. I want to use them on the same view to allow a user to enter all the information on one page. The problem is that ASP.NET MVC allows to pass only one model. What is the best practice to resolve this situation?

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int StreetNumber { get; set; }

    public string Route { get; set;}
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set;  }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public string Coutry { get; set; }

    public int Adresstype { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Ads = new HashSet<Ad>();
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create a **view model** for that exact view - and this is just a class where you can package anything you like - like one of each of your base classes:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

and then you pass this **view model** class into your view and you can easily handle values for both things - users and addresses.